# Python output replaces non ASCII characters with �

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

I am using Python 2.7 to read data from a MySQL table. In MySQL the name looks like this:

> Garasa, Ángel.

But when I print it in Python the output is

> Garasa, �ngel

The character set name in MySQL is utf8. 
This is my Python code:

```
# coding: utf-8

import MySQLdb

connection = MySQLdb.connect     
(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="root",db="jmdb")
cursor = connection.cursor ()
cursor.execute ("select * from actors where actorid=672462;")
data = cursor.fetchall ()
for row in data:
    print  "IMDB Name=",row[4]
    wiki=("".join(row[4]))
    print wiki
```

I have tried decoding it, but get error such as:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 8:
>   invalid start byte

I have read about decoding and UTF-8 but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: You sure it is not latin-1 encoded?

Comment: That's likely your terminal, not Python. What console or terminal are you printing *to* here?

Comment: The coding header has *nothing* to do with loading and printing unicode data. It is only applicable to how Python reads the source code. Once the source code is compiled, the codec header is not used for anything else.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am using Pycharam 5

Comment: Also, what does `print repr(wiki)` show is contained in the object? It'll tell us much more about wether or not the data was loaded from MySQL in the right codec.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I stand corrected:    `print repr(wiki)`
for the original input gives the following: 'Garasa, \xc1ngel'. 
After decoding with Latin-1 as suggested below, the output is: u'Garasa, \xc1ngel'

Comment: Here is a checklist for character set issues with Python and MySQL:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the Mysql driver to return Unicode strings instead. This means that you don't have to deal with decoding in your code.

Simply set `use_unicode=True` in the connection parameters. If the table has been set with a specific encoding then set the `charset` attribute accordingly.

Comment: This works, but yet still remains the [problem of concatenating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570610/python-not-concatenating-string-and-unicode-to-link/)

Answer (score 1):

I think the right character mapping in your case is `cp1252` :

```
>>> s = 'Garasa, Ángel.'
>>> s.decode('utf-8')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#63>", line 1, in <module>
    s.decode('utf-8')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 8: invalid start byte

>>> s.decode('cp1252')
u'Garasa, \xc1ngel.'
>>>
>>> print s.decode('cp1252')
Garasa, Ángel.
```

**EDIT:** It could also be possible that it is `latin-1` as well:

```
>>> s.decode('latin-1')
u'Garasa, \xc1ngel.'
>>> print s.decode('latin-1')
Garasa, Ángel.
```

As `cp1252` and `latin-1` code pages intersects for all codes except the range 128 to 159.

Quoting from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) source (`latin-1`):

> The Windows-1252 codepage coincides with ISO-8859-1 for all codes
>   except the range 128 to 159 (hex 80 to 9F), where the little-used C1
>   controls are replaced with additional characters including all the
>   missing characters provided by ISO-8859-15

And [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) one (`cp1252`):

> This character encoding is a superset of ISO 8859-1, but differs from
>   the IANA's ISO-8859-1 by using displayable characters rather than
>   control characters in the 80 to 9F (hex) range.

Comment: This depends entirely on *your console or terminal environment*. You pasted text into your console or terminal, and Python can only decode that as the bytes you pasted.

Comment: In *my* terminal (the OS X terminal app) I *can* decode pasted text as UTF-8, because that's exactly what my terminal is configured for.

Comment: The OP on the other hand, is loading the data from a MySQL table. Without details about how the data was loaded from MySQL and what console is being printed to, you can't reach *any* conclusion about what codec the data is to be decoded as.

Comment: @MartijnPieters .. I agree...Thanks for the Tips .. but how can you explain that decoding in `utf-8` thrown errors while decoding in `latin-1` or `cp1252` did not?

Comment: @MovieBall .. Consider voting the answer that helped you the most and accepting it.

Comment: Now the output is good, but when I add it to a string that is the prefix for a web site(of Wikipedia API -  as the name of the variable suggests), python doesn't treat them as a whole, and my program can't access the link to parse the page. 
But if the value that return from MySQL is with no special characters (for example
 `Maguire, Tobey`) the link is complete and I the program run smoothly.

Comment: @MovieBall can you update your Question with the relevant code and error msgs if any?

Comment: @MovieBall please don't change the scope of a question - Please create a new question.

Comment: @IronFist see my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570610/python-not-concatenating-string-and-unicode-to-link/)

Comment: @IronFist: Your first link isn't a URL.

Comment: @PeterO. ..URL fixed.