# Python not concatenating string and unicode to link

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, unicode

When I append a Unicode string to the end of str, I can not click on the URL.

Bad:

```
base_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&titles='

url = base_url + u"Ángel_Garasa"
print url
```

[image: The final output for a name with accents]

Good:

```
base_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&titles='

url = base_url + u"Toby_Maquire"
print url
```

[image: The final output for a name without accents]

Comment: Why are you decoding to latin-1?

Comment: This solved the original issue. You can see in the [original post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559847/python-output-replaces-non-ascii-characters-with) what was the issue and why I used this encoding. Of course if you have a solution for the original issue that will avoid this one, it will also be great!

Comment: I'm actually wondering why you would need the special characters to use the url. Why not normalize the input, and the url will still resolve? In python you can get rid of the accents by doing the following: `wiki2 = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', wiki2).encode('ascii','ignore')` after importing `unicodedata`.

Comment: If `.decode('latin1')` works on the SQL data, then the SQL data is *not* UTF-8.

Comment: I've suggested a major edit which I think get's to the crux of the question - your IDE highlights URLs, but your accented character makes your IDE think it's not valid.

Comment: @EVR I need the accent because that's how wikipedia presents the link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&titles=Ángel_Garasa - is a valid page
while https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&titles=Angel_Garasa isn't

Comment: @MarkTolonen I changes the code and added     `use_unicode=True` in the connection and did need to decode anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're printing the results in an IDE, perhaps PyCharm. You need to percent encode a UTF-8 encoded version of the string:

```
import urllib

base_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&titles='
name = u"Ángel_Garasa"

print base_url + urllib.quote(name.encode("utf-8"))
```

This shows: [image: image showing clickable link with percent encoded portion]

In your case you need to update your code, so that the relevant field from the database is percent encoded. You only need to encode this one field to UTF-8 just for the percent encoding.